# Can I remotely choose and control Grub on an Android device?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, remote

This may seem awfully ambitious or like complete nonsense as it probably is.

Is it possible for me and others who have dual booted and use Grub to remotely control Grub and select which system to boot into while being about?

The thing I would like to control my PC on is preferably my phone which is powered by Android. Or any other device to control it with is also fine.

All help will be appreciate.